# Call Featured Image from Parent Page

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am working on a site and each page group has its own featured image.  I am trying to do a conditional statement in the header but not sure how to check for the parent page's featured image.

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail();
} else{?>

    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/BANNER-DEFAULT.jpg"/>


<?php
}
?>
```

I want it to preform like:

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail();
} 

if ( ?????? { // check if the parent page has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail();

}else{?>

    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/BANNER-DEFAULT.jpg"/>


<?php
}
?>
```

Can anyone help with this? I am also considering calling in the banner on the page templates and not the header, but I still need a way to call in the featured image on the Parent Page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want something like the following:

```
<?php 
if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->post_parent ) ) { 
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->post_parent );
}
?>
```

Calling `the_post_thumbnail();` should return the current post thumbnail, whereas using `get_the_post_thumbnail();` will allow you to specify the ID, using the parent ID in your case.

[Function Reference for get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Also, if you're doing this outside of the loop, you'll need the `$post` global variable, as seen [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Testing_for_sub-Pages).

Comment: Thanks! Works great